# How do I allow registration for one day of a multi-day event?

Tags: civievent, price-sets

A use-case has come up where there is a need to hold a multi-day event where participants can register for "One day only". So if the event was Wed, Thurs & Fri, they could choose "Friday only" at registration.

I am thinking that Price Sets handles this nicely, although the rest of the event confirmations, reminders, etc. would not acknowledge that they are only attending for one of the days.

Anyone have experience with this or ideas beyond just using price sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have successfully used price sets for exactly that purpose.

You can customise the event confirmation/receipt at **Mailings > Message Templates > System Workflow Messages**.   These are written using [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

{if $event.id  eq 'XX'} will let you selectively customise the receipts for a particular event.

{if $line.label eq 'Friday only'} should let you customise at the individual line item level once you are in the line item loop.

For scheduled reminders you may be able to use Search Builder to create smart groups based on the fee label and so send different reminders depending on the day(s) of attendance using "Limit to - Group ".

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful tips. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that including the dates as part of the price set labels would make this approach viable.

The other approach is cart-style event checkout, but that's a far more complicated setup that I don't think is warranted here.